# What was Aragorn talking about when he said "Helms Deep helped them survive in the past"?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-two-towers

In the Lord of the Rings movie *The Two Towers*, during the preparation of people's movement from Edoras to Helm's Deep, Aragorn says something like:

> Helm’s Deep helped them survive in the past

meaning the people of Rohan.

What exactly he was talking about? Which battle he was talking about and when did it occur?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## The War against the Dunlendings, TA 2758

A Dunlending man Freca, claiming descent from King Fréawine, rode to Meduseld and asked for King Helm's daughter's hand for his son Wulf. Helm, however, mocked him and killed Freca in Meduseld.  His people fled for a while. However, four years later they were to return and the battle is detailed below:

> Four years later (2758) great troubles came to Rohan, and no help could be sent from Gondor, for three fleets of the Corsairs attacked it and there was war on all its coasts. **At the same time Rohan was again invaded from the East, and the Dunlendings seeing their chance came over the Isen and down from Isengard.**  It  was  soon known  that  Wulf  was  their  leader.  They  were  in  great force, for they were joined by enemies of Gondor that landed in the mouths of Lefnui and Isen. The Rohirrim were defeated and their land was overrun; and those who were not slain or enslaved fled to the dales of the mountains. **Helm was driven back  with  great  loss  from  the  Crossings  of  Isen  and  took  refuge  in  the Hornburg and the ravine behind (which was after known as Helm’s Deep).** There  he  was  besieged.  Wulf  took  Edoras  and  sat  in  Meduseld  and  called himself king. There Haleth Helm’s son fell, last of all, defending the doors.
> <sub>Return of the Kings - Book 7, Appendix A: Annals of the Kings and Rulers, II House of Eorl</sub>

The end of the war came after the death of Helm, the attack led by Helm's  sister-son, Fréaláf, after which he was crowned King and began the Second Line:

> ‘Soon after the winter broke. Then Fréaláf, son of Hild, Helm’s sister, **came  down  out  of  Dunharrow,  to  which  many  had  fled;  and  with  a  small company of desperate men he surprised Wulf in Meduseld and slew him, and regained  Edoras.** ... The Eastern invaders perished or withdrew; and there  came  help  at  last  from  Gondor,  by  the  roads  both  east and  west  of  the mountains. Before the year (2759) was ended the Dunlendings were driven out, even from Isengard; and then Fréaláf became king.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

This is again recounted earlier in the chapter under the Kings of Men:

> At the same time the  Rohirrim  were  assailed  from  the  west  and  the  east,  and  their  land  was overrun, and they were driven into the dales of the White Mountains. In that year (2758) the Long Winter began with cold and great snows out of the North and the East which lasted for almost five months. Helm of Rohan and both his sons perished in that war; and there was misery and death in Eriador and in Rohan. **But in Gondor south of the mountains things were less evil, and before spring  came  Beregond  son  of  Beren  had  overcome  the  invaders.  At  once  he sent aid to Rohan.**
> <sub>ibid: The Stewards</sub>

---

#### As for the tales of the strength of Helm, these are noted below.

> ‘Soon afterwards the Long Winter began, and Rohan lay under snow for nearly five months (November to March, 2758–9). Both the Rohirrim and their foes  suffered  grievously  in the  cold,  and  in  the  dearth  that  lasted  longer.  In Helm’s Deep there was a great hunger after Yule; and being in despair, against the king’s counsel, Háma his younger son led men out on a sortie and foray, but  they  were  lost  in  the  snow.  Helm  grew  fierce  and  gaunt  for  famine  and grief; and the dread of him alone was worth many men in the defence of the Burg.  **He  would  go  out  by  himself,  clad  in  white,  and  stalk  like  a  snow-troll into  the  camps  of  his  enemies,  and  slay  many  men  with  his  hands.  It  was believed that  if  he  bore  no  weapon  no  weapon  would  bite  on  him.  The Dunlendings said that if he could find no food he ate men.** That tale lasted long in  Dunland.  Helm  had  a  great  horn,  and  soon  it  was  marked  that  before  he sallied forth he would blow a blast upon it that echoed in the Deep; and then so great a fear fell on his enemies that instead of gathering to take him or kill him they fled away down the Coomb.
>
> ‘One night men heard the horn blowing, but Helm did not return. In the morning there came a sun-gleam, the first for long days, and they saw a white figure  standing  still  on  the  Dike,  alone,  for  none  of  the  Dunlendings  dared come near. **There stood Helm, dead as a stone, but his knees were unbent. Yet men said that the horn was still heard at times in the Deep and the wraith of Helm would walk among the foes of Rohan and kill men with fear.**
> <sub>ibid.: II House of Eorl</sub>

Comment: After the first quote, I think you meant to write "The end of the war came after the death of **Wulf**, by the hands of **Helm's** sister-son, ...". I didn't edit it as you might have meant to refer to Helm's death (although that wasn't by the hand of his sister-son).

Comment: I meant to say Helm, but not to say Helm was killed by Frealaf. I don't know if I've worded it better now

Answer (score 12):

In the Appendices of *LotR*, the early history of Rohan is recounted briefly.  One of the Annals says:

> 2758 -- Rohan attacked from west and east and overrun. Gondor attacked by fleets of the Corsairs. Helm of Rohan takes refuge in Helm's Deep. Wulf seizes Edoras. 2758-9: The Long Winter follows. Great suffering and loss of life in Eriador and Rohan.

In much greater detail:

> Four years later (2758) great troubles came to Rohan, and no help could be sent from Gondor, for three fleets of the Corsairs attacked it and there was war on all its coasts. At the same time Rohan was again invaded from the East, and the Dunlendings seeing their chance came over the Isen and down from Isengard. It was soon known that Wulf was their leader. The were in great force, for they were joined by enemies of Gondor that landed in the mouths of Lefnui and Isen.
>
> The Rohirrim were defeated and their land was overrun; and those who were not slain or enslaved fled to the dales of the mountains. Helm was driven back with great loss from the Crossings of Isen and took refuge in the Hornburg and the ravine behind (which was after known as Helm's Deep). There he was besieged. Wulf took Edoras and sat in Meduseld and called himself king. There Haleth Helm's son fell, last of all, defending the doors.
>     'Soon afterwards the Long Winter began, and Rohan lay under snow for nearly five months (November to March, 2758-9). Both the Rohirrim and their foes suffered grievously in the cold, and in the dearth that lasted longer. In Helm's Deep there was a great hunger after Yule;
>
> ...
>
> 'Soon after the winter broke. Then Fréaláf, son of Hild, Helm's sister, came down out of Dunharrow, to which many had fled; and with a small company of desperate men he surprised Wulf in Meduseld and slew him, and regained Edoras. There were great floods after the snows, and the vale of Entwash became a vast fen. The Eastern invaders perished or withdrew; and there came help at last from Gondor, by the roads both east and west of the mountains. Before the year (2759) was ended the Dunlendings were driven out, even from Isengard; and then Fréaláf became king.